# Confusion with Haskell type inference

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I don't understand why the following function works:

```
isLongerThanN :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> Bool
isLongerThanN n xs = length xs > fromIntegral n
```

but the following doesn't:

```
isLongerThanN' :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> Bool
isLongerThanN' n xs = length xs > n
```

which throws the error

```
Could not deduce (n ~ Int)
    from the context (Integral n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 isLongerThanN' :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> Bool
      at blah.hs:140:1-35
      `n' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            isLongerThanN' :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> Bool
          at blah.hs:140:1
    In the second argument of `(>)', namely `n'
    In the expression: length xs > n
    In an equation for `isLongerThanN'':
        isLongerThanN' n xs = length xs > n
```

(which I've likely misunderstood)

If anything, I would expect it to be the other way around, since **fromIntegral** is effectively broadening variable n's type.

Comment: Don't write `if foo then True else False`. It's the same as just `foo`.

Comment: you're right, thanks; I've modified it, but that's not the question

Comment: That's why he didn't post it as an answer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the expression that doesn't work

```
isLongerThanN' :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> Bool
isLongerThanN' n xs = length xs > n
```

`n` can be any integer-y type, so it can be passed an `Integer` or `Word` or `Int`. `(>)` has type `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` so both its left and right operand have to be of the same type. `length xs` returns an `Int` so this type has to be that.  But, `n` can be any `Integral`, not necessarily `Int`, so we need some way of allowing `n` to be converted to an `Int`. This is what `fromIntegral` does (the fact that it also allows `n` to be any `Num` is basically irrelevant).

We could expand the working version to look like:

```
toInt :: Integral n => n -> Int
toInt = fromIntegral

isLongerThanN :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> Bool
isLongerThanN n xs = length xs > toInt n
```

which makes it clearer that we're using a specialised version of `fromIntegral`.

(Note that `isLongerThanN n xs = fromIntegral (length xs) > n` also works, because it allows the result of `length` to match up with the type of `n`.)

Comment: Though, note that the choice of which one you convert can affect the result; with the last example `isLongerThanN (0 :: Word8) [1..256] == False` due to overflow.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it. Thanks a lot. Why the non-working version doesn't work wasn't  the problem for me, but I was reading the type signature fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b wrongly.